# Using tf.where() and tf.gather_nd() with None dimension

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, tensorflow2.0

I am tackling a machine learning problem in which I feed my network with data of shape `(batch_size, n_objects, n_features)`. So, each training instance comes with a given number of objects, each of them having a given number of features. Among these features I have electric charge, and while writing a custom loss function I would like to use *only the neutral objects* to compute it. Thus, starting from a tensor of shape `(batch_size, n_objects, n_features)` I would like to get a tensor of shape `(batch_size, n_neutral_objects, n_features)`. In doing this, I'm facing a couple of problems.

First of all, I made a try by creating a tensor by hand. I have 3 training instances, each one having 2 objects, each one having 3 features. I try to get the neutral objects using `tf.where()` and `tf.gather()` methods in the following way (suppose that electric charge is the 2nd feature):

```
a = tf.constant([[[3.5, 0, 6], [2.1, 1, 2.9]], [[1.5, 1, 4.5], [2.0, 0, 4.2]], [[6.2, 0, 6.1], [4.8, 1, 3.4]]]) #toy input tensor                                                                                                                                                                 
b = tf.where(a[:,:,1] == 0) #find neutral objects (charge is 2nd feature)
c = tf.gather_nd(a,b) #gather them
print(c)
```

This kind of works, as I get

```
[[3.5 0.  6. ]
 [2.  0.  4.2]
 [6.2 0.  6.1]], shape=(3, 3), dtype=float32)
```

as an output, which are the desired objects. But I've somehow lost the first dimension, as I don't want a tensor of shape `(3, 3)`, but rather one of shape `(3, 1, 3)`, namely still 3 input instances, each one having only one neutral object, each of them having 3 features.

Things get worse if I plug my approach into my TF model. In this real-life case, my batch size is `None` and I am thus dealing with tensors of shape `(None, 4000, 14)` (so 4000 objects for each training instance, 14 features each). This is the code I tried

```
def get_neutrals(tensor):
        print("tensor.get_shape()", tensor.get_shape())
        charges = tensor[:,:,4] #charge is the 5th feature in this case
        print("charges.get_shape()", charges.get_shape())
        where_neutrals = tf.where(charges == 0) # get the neutrals only                                                                                                                         
        print("where_neutrals.get_shape()", where_neutrals.get_shape())
        print("tf.gather_nd(tensor, where_neutrals).get_shape()", tf.gather_nd(tensor, where_neutrals).get_shape())
        return tf.gather_nd(tensor, where_neutrals)
```

and this is what I get printed if I call my method:

```
tensor.get_shape() (None, 4000, 14)
charges.get_shape() (None, 4000)
where_neutrals.get_shape() (None, 2)
tf.gather_nd(tensor, where_neutrals).get_shape() (None, 14)
```

The last two shapes are completely unexpected and I don't know why they look like this. Can anyone here help with this?

Thanks a lot, cheers,

F.

Comment: `tf.where` return indices, so if you apply it on a tensor with `N` dimensions, you get a tensor of shape `(None,N)`. The first dimension will always be unknown, as there is no guarantee that the number of element that fit the condition is constant across batches. For the same reason, when you call `tf.gather_nd`, one dimension is squeezed, because there is no guarantee that the resulting tensor has the same number of elements across the indexed dimension. (Tensors have fixed shape). Hope that helps.

Comment: Hello @Lescurel, thanks for your comment. Indeed I see your point and I did not thought that, indeed, I am not guaranteed that the number of objects I want to pick is constant for each training instance. I guess this means that I should change my approach to the problem. Thanks, your answer was helpful, cheers!